# xml 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import re
import ssl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ctx=ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
htm = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()


trees = ET.fromstring(htm)
tree = trees.findall('comments/comment')

for x in tree:
    print ('Count', x.find('count'.text))
```

---

Dear All,

Above is my code and I expect this code will extract the number of the item count in the xml document. However, when I run the code, it says AttributeError:'str' object has no attribute 'text'.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

---

Comment: print ('Count', x.find('count').text)

Comment: `'count'.text` won't work, no. That's asking if the `'count'` string has the attribute `text`. Did you mean to use `x.find('count').text` perhaps?

Comment: Yes！！！Problem solved! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake on the line

```
 print ('Count', x.find('count'.text))
```

You're trying to access text attribute of a string "count" instead of the find() operation result. The correct line would be

```
print ('Count', x.find('count').text)
```

Comment: I got it! Problem solved!!!Thank you so much!